# WPF Binding a collection of collections to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

To simplify my problem, let's say that I have a property, that I am binding my DataGrid to:

```
public List<LibrarySection> Library { get; set; }
```

Then in each LibrarySection I have

```
class LibrarySection
{
   public string SectionName{ get; set; }
   public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

And book look like this:

```
class Book
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Author { get; set; }
   public string BookID { get; set; }
}
```

Now how can I bind to property Library, to achieve in a DataGrid a list of all the books:
[image: Book table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expecting that LibrarySection is the `DataContext` of your DataGrid you can simply add `Books` as it's `ItemsSource`.

You if `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to `true` this already display your items **but** if you want to define your own columns (change headers and stuff) you should set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`.

You then can add `Columns` and tell each `Column` to bind a specific `Property` of the object contained in the collection your `ItemsSource` is binding to.

```
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding Books}
          AutoGenerateColumns="false"><!--should be false-->
     <!-- Define custom columns -->
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Name}" Header="BookName" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Author}" Header="Book Author" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{BookID}" Header="BookID" />             
      </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Normally you should have a `ViewModel` which has a `LibrarySection`-Property.
If so simply use `ItemsSource="{Binding Library.Books}"`

I also recommend using `ObservableCollection<LibrarySection>` and `ObservableCollection<Book>` instead of `List<T>` since it automatically updated if any of the values change.

Comment: Thank you :) Yes I have ViewModel, but it doesn't have `LiblarySection` but a List<LibrarySection> called Library, as I stated in my question. Also I agree, that i should use `ObservableCollection<T>` but this is not up to me

Comment: you can also bind on a single library using `{Binding Library[0].Books}` - or simply create a new `DataGrid` for each Library. Starting with WPF [www.wpf-tutorial.com](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/) **and/or** [www.wpftutorial.net](https://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) might be very helpful. There are alot of samples using `DataGrid` too. `Grouping` might be interesting for your scenario too !

Comment: Hey, I misunderstood you a little. I didn't have time to check your answer properly. Data context of my grid is Library - List<LibrarySections>, not a Library Section itself. How can i Databind to `Library` in order to get list of books? I need to all LibrarySections be in the same DataGrid

Comment: Is it possible to provide an alternative source for the column headers? ie I have a list of strings for column headers, and a 2d array representing all the records to be inserted

Comment: huh, turns out i can, by providing datasource and doing a databind in the codeBehind